# How to Calculate the largest slope using of data points of 2 arrays: (Explanation in description)

Tags: c#

My code so far:
I have three arrays but only need the first 2 to calculate slopes for this project. I have read in a file which is of the format 3 columns and 'n' rows. I have split the file into three listed columns and now I need to calculate the greatest absolute value slope. To expand, say I have 2 arrays of doubles {1,2,3,4,5,6} and {7,8,9,10,11,12} then the data points are (1,7), (2,8) etc. We will get 6 data points and I need to get the slope between them all. And the greatest absolute value slope is the one we need to return.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
string file1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file1.txt");

List<double> Array1 = new List<double>();
List<double> Array2 = new List<double>();
List<double> Array3 = new List<double>();

IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\File1.txt");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] columns = line.Split(',');

    if (columns.Length != 3)
    {
        continue; // skips this line
    }

    Array1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[0]));
    Array2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[1]));
    Array3.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[2]));
}

static double GreatestSlope(double[] x, double[] y)
{
int size = x.length; 
double ret = 0.0;
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    for( int j = i+1; j < size; j++ )
    {
        double slope = (y[j]-y[i])/(x[j]-x[i]);
        if( slope > ret )
            {
             ret = slope;
             Console.WriteLine(i);
             Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `GreatestSlope` need two double[]'s as arguments?

Comment: My mistake I edited that into the original code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by slope you mean geometric slope. In that case, we can just loop through all of the possibilities. Because the slope between A and B is the same as the slope between B and A, the code can be made more efficient by making the inner loop only go from `i+1` to the end.

```
static double GreatestSlope(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    int size = x.length; // For security, Math.Min(x.length,y.length) would be better.
    double ret = 0.0;
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = i+1; j < size; j++ )
        {
            double slope = (y[j]-y[i])/(x[j]-x[i]);
            if( slope > ret )
                ret = slope;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Why j=i+1 and not j=i?

Comment: @TheNovice913 Then we will calculate the slope between two identical points `(y[i]-y[i])/(x[i]-x[i])`, giving 0.0/0.0, which gives `N/A`. It won't affect the result, since any boolean operation with `N/A` returns false.

Comment: Ah yes. I see now thank you for teaching me this. By the way I ran the code and said in the main     Console.WriteLine(GreatestSlope(Array1,Array2)); and I got the greatest slope to be infinity!

Comment: @TheNovice913 You probably have two coordinates that share the same `x` coordinate, to which that answer is indeed correct.

Comment: @TheNovice913 Also, it appears that you just made your account today. Welcome to SO! If you feel an answer is sufficient, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to the up/down vote button.

Comment: This is not the case with the data points all of the x coordinates are different. Maybe the code is calculating the slope of a single point? i.e. the slope between (1,2) and (1.2)? which is infinity also.

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming!

Comment: @TheNovice913 The slope between `(1,2)` and `(1,2)` will be evaluated just as the case where `j=i`; you get a special type of double called `N/A` or `NaN`, which always returns false on comparisons and thus the `if` statement will never execute.

Comment: When I write the function value to the console it reads as 'infinity' . I tried switching around the order for GreatestSlope(array1,array2) and got zero for the slope. Any idea why?

Comment: @TheNovice913 If you are getting incorrect results, try printing out your arrays first to make sure that the file parsing is working correctly. Judging from the output, all of the `x` coordinates must be the same. Make sure that by `columns[0]` you aren't just getting a list of '('s. I'm not familiar with C#, but that function works for manually initialized arrays.

Comment: I have printed out the arrays using a 'foreach' loop and console.writeline and all of the values appear correctly!

Comment: if you can help with this please let me know

Comment: @TheNovice913 If you want you can send a pastebin of your file, your code, and the output.

Comment: No need my code is exactly as above with your code added in then in the main a Console.WriteLine(GreatestSlope(array1.ToArray,array2.ToArray). It returns 'infinity' 'press any key to continue. Simple as that nothing else

Comment: @TheNovice913 From my tests it works fine. Debug it by putting a `WriteLine` that outputs the x,y coordinates inside of the `if` so you can see what's generating the infinity.

Comment: So I edited the original code. Where do I move the console.WriteLines to, to correctly print out all the points?

Comment: @TheNovice913 Put braces after `if( slope > ret )` so that `ret = slope;` is enclosed as well as a `WriteLine` that will output x[i], y[i], x[j], y[j] to find the problematic points.

Comment: I found the error. Thank you so much for that!! My slopes all happen to be negative so I switched it to slope < ret. It now prints out the correct max slope but this also causes a problem. I need to get it to print out the position values that this slope occurs at in array2 and 1, Do I say console.WriteLine(x[i] +x[j])? And where would I place this WriteLine in the code?

Comment: @TheNovice913 x[i]+x[j] would calculate the sum first and then write it to the console, rather than writing it separately. I would suggest returning a `List` instead of a double, because when `GreatestArray` returns a double it isn't going to have enough information. Make a List, populate it with the values you want to return (i, j, and the slope) and then return that. Then, in `Main`, try `List<double> arr = GreatestSl...`, `int i = arr.ToArray()[0];` and `Console.WriteLine("("+x[i]+","+y[i]+")");` and do the same with `j` and the slope. I would suggest Google/YouTube for more reference.